# Verilog - generate weighted random numbers

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to generate random single bits and this is simple as long as you want a normal randomization:

```
wire R;
assign R = $random % 2;
```

What I am looking for is a sort of weighted probability like:

```
wire R;
assign R = 60%(0) || 40%(1);
```

Forgive me if it is not conform to standard Verilog code, it is just to give an idea of what I want.
Can anyone help me out?
Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SystemVerilog solution has a distribution method within `randomize` called `dist`. Weights are assigned by `value_or_range := weight` or `value_or_range :/ distributed_weight`. This exert from the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 18.5.4 page 476 gives a clear example:

> When weights are applied to ranges, they can be applied to each value in the range, or they can be applied to the range as a whole. For example: 
>   **`x dist { [100:102] := 1, 200 := 2, 300 := 5}`**
>   means x is equal to 100, 101, 102, 200, or 300 with a weighted ratio of 1-1-1-2-5, and
>   **`x dist { [100:102] :/ 1, 200 := 2, 300 := 5}`**
>   means x is equal to one of 100, 101, 102, 200, or 300 with a weighted ratio of
>   1/3-1/3-1/3-2-5.

`dist` is used in randomization so it needs to be mare of a `randomize() with` (or a class `constraint`). `randomize` returns a success bit, therefore it should be in called within an `assert`, `void'()`, or the RHS of an assignment.

In your we can set the weight of 0 to 6 and the weight of 1 to 4, creating a total weight of 10 with a 60/40 distribution. Example:

```
reg R;
initial begin
  assert( randomize(R) with { R dist { 0 := 6, 1 := 4 }; } );
end
```

From more about `dist` see [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 18.5.4 "Distribution".

Answer (score 3):

Create a random integer then based on Value return 1 or 0; NB you may want to seed your random number, for repeatability use the same seed. This way when a test fails it can be debugged.

`$urandom` works a little different to `$random` it doe not update the seed value so should only be seeded the first time it is called in a thread (always block). It is also thread safe, each always block works independently.

```
initial begin
  $urandom(seed);
  $urandom;
  $urandom;
end

integer temp;
reg     r   ;

always @ ... begin
  temp = $urandom; //Range: +2_147_483_647 -2_147_483_648
  // weighting; 0 would be 50:50
  // real weighting is (0.1 + 0.5), 0.5 inherent from positive number.
  r =  (temp > (2_147_483_647*0.1);  
end
```

NB: the random functions are not synthesizable and should only be used for testbenches. if you want a random number for synthesis check out [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14497877/97073)

Answer (score 1):

For Verilog you can always so something like:

```
integer R;

R = ($dist_uniform(0,100) < 60) : $dist_uniform(0,5) : $dist_uniform(6,10)
```

and this in SystemVerilog would be the same as:

```
std::randomize(R) with {R dist {[0:5] :/60, [6:10] :/ 40} ;};
```

You could also do this procedural code:
    randcase
    60: R = 1;
    40: R = 0;
    endcase

Comment: In VCS, std::randomize() is much slower than $dist_uniform().

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
wire R;
if ($random[7:0]>(40*255/100))
  assign R = 1'b0;
else
  assign R = 1'b1;
```

I'm assuming that the algorithm that `$random` uses produces numbers that are equally random whatever bits you take from it.

Answer (score 0):

Following Code Will Generate Random Variable as Per Your Requirement :

```
program top;
    class Packet;
        rand reg R;
        constraint percentage {R dist {1:=60,0:=40};};
        function void display;
            $display("Random Reg : %0d",this.R);
        endfunction
    endclass
    Packet P;

    initial 
    begin
        P = new;
        repeat(10)
            begin
                P.randomize();
                P.display;
            end
    end
endprogram
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems not so hard at verilog.

```
reg [7:0] R;
reg rand_bit;
R = $random();
if (R < 76)
   rand_bit = 1'b0;
else
   rand_bit = 1'b1;
```

Here I assume that $random is pretty uniform. I think it should work :)